# Js click property not working on html loaded by js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a dynamic page in which i am loadin 10 element by default. after that if user scroll doun i am apppending more element to this page by js (appending data by ajax).
and on click of a tag i am doing some js work

I am using

```
$('.atnd_modal').click(function(){
 alert("dsfds");
 });
```

not

```
 onclick ="function()" and i dont want to do that onclick.
```

Problem i am facing that this js is working perfectely for first 10 result but after that it stop working for the  block i have appended by js.

how can to do it working for both the cases ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try jquery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for event delegation. It will work on dynamic loaded element on DOM also.

```
$('body').on('click','.atnd_modal', function(){
   alert("dsfds");
});
```

> **Delegated events** have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

Your click event is not working because when you use `click()` it will attach this handler to all elements having `atnd_modal` class, but when new element loading in `DOM` that event is not attached automatically with new element. For previous elements it will work fine but for new element it won't. So here comes **Delegated events**. We shall attach event to parent element with `on()` or [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bind an event to the dynamically added new elements you have to use event delegation :-

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Change your code like this, use Jquery [On](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
 $('body').on('click','.atnd_modal', function(){
   alert("dsfds");
 });
```

Comment: thanks ssilas777. Its working fine. Can you explain more what happen in this case ?

Comment: @SunilKumar Check my edit, since you are adding elements dynamically, you have to delegate the events from an element guaranteed to be present.